# OpenCV - how do you access the raspberry pi camera?

Tags: camera, opencv

I am trying to access the raspberry pi camera with OpenCV. I found some code that I want to use but I think something is wrong with this code:
`video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)`
because later when I use this code:
`crop_img = frame[60:120, 0:160]`
 I get this error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

How do I fix this?

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant to the question which is really a general Python one and more specific to openCV.

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=202781

Comment: This is a very thorny issue.... the RPi camera does not play very well with OpenCV mainly because it does different image acquisition formats... but... there is a way to do it. I found this article to be very helpful and managed to get its code running... # https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-create-object-detection-with-opencv Also you might find these links useful too # https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-read-display-and-save-images-with-opencv-on-raspberry-pi # https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/recipes2.html # https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1